# Ruby on Rails, instead of update make new entry to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I made a simple demo site, with an model for the patients name `(name:string)` and another model with the treatment `(content:text)`. I created this "project" to learn more about the `accepts_nested_attribute` for tag and the fields_for tag. 
Now my problem is that on the patient show page i created an nested formula for the treatment , like you can see here:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
<b>Name:</b>
    <%= @patient.name %>
</p>

<ol>
  <% for treatment in @patient.treatments %>
     <li><%= treatment.content %></li>
   <% end %>
</ol>

<%= form_for(@patient) do |f| %>

<%= f.fields_for :treatments do |builder| %>

<div class="field">
   <%= builder.label :content %><br />
   <%= builder.text_field :content %>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_patient_path(@patient) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', patients_path %>
```

So my problem is that in the `builder.text_field :content` better called the input shows up the last saved treatment from `<%= builder.content %>`, but i want that he does not update it instead i want to add new treatments! Hopefully somebody understands me! Thanks

Comment: did you add accept_nested_attributes :treatments to your model and can you write your controller method of patient#create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create separate controller for creating only the `treatment`, eg.

```
# treatments_controller.rb
class TreatmentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @treatment = @patient.treatments.new(params[:treatment])
    if @treatment.save
      redirect_to @patient
    else
      # handle unsuccessful treatment save
    end
  end
end

# routes.rb:
resources :patients do
  resources :treatments, only: :create
end

# form:
<%= form_for @patient, @treatment do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You should also set `@treatment` variable in the `patient#show` action, like this:

```
@treatment = @patient.treatments.new
```